# Vertically align buttons with wrapped text, side by side

Tags: html, css, button, vertical-alignment

I want to show multiple buttons side by side, which is not the problem.
But I have one or more buttons with wrapped text because the button is too small (this should be).

If the text of one button is wrapped, they do not appear correctly side by side.
The button with wrapped text is lower than the other.
What causes this and how can I prevent it?

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>TEST</button><button>TEST WRAPPED TEXT</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

buttons are `inline` elements which are aligned `baseline` vertically by default...

...so use `vertical-align:top` to `button`...

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>TEST</button><button>TEST WRAP TEXT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: baseline, ok makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**[display:flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)** on the `.container` does the trick.

Since you need the buttons to be `50%` of its container, it is the best way to go.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  flex: 1;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>TEST</button><button>TEST WRAPPED TEXT</button>
</div>
```